# jQuery fails to update custom attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/373/

As you can see from this fiddle, I can set the attribute, but I can't change it after that. Is there a way to fix this so I can update it?

Here's the code, from the fiddle:

```
<input type="text" id="tester" value="some data">
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

$(function(){
    $('#tester').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $("#one").html($('#tester').attr('readonly'));
    $('#tester').attr('readonly', 'true');
    $("#two").html($('#tester').attr('readonly'));
    $('#tester').attr('readonly', 'BROKEN');
    $("#three").html($('#tester').attr('readonly'));
});
```

Output:

```
readonly
readonly
readonly
```

Edit: Updated code to use an input. I didn't think it would matter.

Edit: Thanks to phillip100 for pointing out that I should be using prop() not attr(). Also, readonly gets set to false with a boolean false, but it's always true with a string.

```
$('#tester').prop('readonly', false); //correct
$('#tester').prop('readonly', 'false'); //incorrect
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/378/

Comment: `readonly` is a **property** related to input elements and as a property should be handled with `.prop()`

Comment: prop does not appear to work either: http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/374/

Comment: yes, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/375/ . You may want to read about [**`.prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: Ok, I guess my browser cache messed me up. It's working now. http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/378/

Comment: You can use also [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check the property http://jsfiddle.net/k3Grd/377/

Answer (score 1):

How you want to place an attr like **readonly** to one div, it doesn't make sense.

You can add **readonly** to inputs, selects, and textarea ....

Answer (score 1):

Change `.attr()` to `.data()` and it will work. As @DarkteK pointed out, `readonly` is only for input fields.